# How can I apply LaTeX command and environment wrappers to singleline or multiline Visual Selections in ViM?

Tags: vim

I modified some code I found here to work for LaTeX. I demonstrate the desired output for two cases. Please have a look at

- Dealing with LaTeX Commands
- Dealing with LaTeX Environments

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Wrap_a_visual_selection_in_an_HTML_tag

## Dealing with LaTeX Commands

### Given:

```
elephant
```

1. visually select "elephant"
2. press F7
3. enter "test"

### Output:

```
\test{elephant}
```

### Example Code Code for `VisualcommandTagWrap`

This works for singleline selections. **I'd like to make it work for multiline selections.**
Simply select text to wrap using your visual selector, then press F7.

```
" Wrap visual selection in a latex command tag.
map <F7> : call VisualcommandTagWrap()
function! VisualcommandTagWrap()
  let tag = input("Tag to wrap block: ")
  if len(tag) > 0
    normal `>
    if &selection == 'exclusive' "set selection=exclusive means position before the cursor marks the end of the selection vs. inclusive
      exe "normal i\\".tag."}"
    else
      exe "normal a\}"
    endif
    normal `<
    exe "normal i\\".tag."{"
    normal `<
  endif
endfunction
```

## Dealing with LaTeX Environments

### Given:

```
elephant
```

1. visually select "elephant"
2. press F7
3. enter "test"

### Output:

```
\begin{test}
elephant
\end{test}
```

### Example Code for `VisualenvironmentTagWrap`

I do not know how to implement functions that cover multiple lines.

---

## Additional Examples

For those unfamiliar with LaTeX. There are two situations to satisfy requirements for LaTeX commands and environments.

```
Here is some visual mode selected text.
And another line of visual mode selected text.
```

### Command Situation:

1. type function key defined in .vimrc to call function
2. vim prompts for user input (e.g. "Please enter name of command:")
3. vim surrounds selection with command.

Result:

```
\inputstep2{Here is some visual mode selected text.
And another line of visual mode selected text.}
```

### Environment Situation

1. type function key defined in .vimrc to call function
2. vim prompts for user input (e.g. "Please enter name of environment:")
3. vim surrounds selection with environment.

Result:

```
\begin{inputstep2}
Here is some visual mode selected text.
And another line of visual mode selected text.
\end{inputstep2}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

You can store the text you want (like `test`) in register `a`.

```
        :let @a='test'
```

(Until you change it, it will remain the same and can be reused. If you want it to be changed, you have to follow the step again.)

**Step 2:**
Then, select the the text using visual selection (`v`, `V` or `ctrl V`) and then press escape to cancel the selection.

**Step 3;**
Keep the cursor on anywhere in the screen, (preferably in the line where you want to surround with) and press `\s` in normal mode.

Put the following mapping in ~/.vimrc file.
Let's create a mapping to wrap around.

For first example: (begin and end type)

```
       :nmap \s '<O\begin{<C-R>a<ESC>}'>o\end{<C-R>a}
```

For second example: (begin type)

```
       :nmap \s '<O\{<C-R>a<ESC>'>a}
```

Comment: That is not dynamic like the original post's version.

Comment: If you can give one or more different examples, I will try to give it generic :)

Comment: If you try out the `VisualcommandTagWrap`, you'll see that it prompts you for text input (e.g. `Tag to wrap block: `). The input would have been "test" in your answer to result in `\begin{test}visualselection\end{test}`

Comment: Alright, I will modify the answer to make a similar function of what you said. Since I don't know latex, it would be better if you could some more examples and expected outputs.

Comment: I've added two more examples, one for commands and one for environments.

Comment: @macmadness86 edited the answer. Check whether it suits your case. If not, we can make minor modifications.